# How can I move all Mutt mail into home folder?

Tags: mutt, dotfiles

I want to move all my mail into my ~/.mail folder. I want my inbox ( $spoolfile ) , sent and postponed. That's all my mail folders, I let gmail take care of the rest.

So would this go in my .muttrc ?

```
set spoolfile= ~/.mail/inbox 

$MAIL \
=inbox \
```

What am I missing? Know of a simple tutorial?